# Chinese/Spanish dual national entering Schengen area

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, dual-nationality, chinese-citizens, spanish-citizens

I got a question after I got my Spanish citizenship. I have a Spanish passport now，I still have the permanent resident card from Spain.

Also I am Chinese… I am planing to go back to Europe (Greece, France, etc.)
I am wondering if I still can use my Chinese passport and Spanish resident card to enter Europe?

Cause I would like to keep a stamp on my Chinese passport so that the government won't find out I have two nationalities.

Comment: by the way...according to the law in Spain.after I got the nationality..the resident card should be taken by the citizenship department..but somehow..they didn't take mine

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel

Comment: Technically, you are not a "dual national" -- under Article 9 of the PRC nationality law, you automatically lost PRC nationality the moment you voluntarily naturalized in Spain, even if the PRC government doesn't know about it. You would just be a (solely) Spanish national who is pretending to be a PRC national.

Answer (score 1):

> by the way...according to the law in Spain.after I got the nationality..the resident card should be taken by the citizenship department..but somehow..they didn't take mine

Correct. They should have taken the card and you shouldn't use it at this point. It's far easier to enter and leave the Schengen area with your new Spanish passport.

Best practice for dual passport holders: choose whatever passport is easiest (and allowed) but always enter and leave a country/region with the same passport (if there are exit controls).

You can switch passports during a trip: Example: you can leave Spain on your Spanish passport and enter to China on your Chinese one.

This being said, China has fairly strict rules about dual citizenship and typically doesn't recognize it. If they find out you have a Spanish passport, they may revoke your Chinese one.

Comment: While the "best practice" part of your answer is technically correct IMHO the main point of the OP's question is that he fears the Chinese government finding out and is looking for ways to minimize his exposure.

Comment: you absolutely right！ after I came to Europe . when I back to China..they might check my Chinese passport and question why I don't have any entry stamp from Schengen.  that‘s why I am asking if I could use the Chinese passport + permanent card to enter the schengen. in order to get a stamp

Comment: @upcomingfortune see [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/52100/19400) for a way to manage this by traveling through a third country.